# Waypoint generator between 2 points on 2d map

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm now trying to generate straight sync points on my 2D map path.
In other words I want to spilt distance between point A on map for example X : 301 Y : 679 to point B X : 360 Y : 630, every 8 unit of distance is passed.
Every 8 distance unit calculated by `sqrt(pow(a_x - b_x, 2), pow(a_y - b_y, 2))`.
 I want to obtain next coordinates on map, like by a a_x + distance and b_y + distance.
I tried to do it but it didn't work, x axis doesnt change propertly.
Here is my code :

```
float base_x = active->getX();
    float base_y = active->getY();

    float destx = incoming_packet.get()->getFloat(4);
    float desty = incoming_packet.get()->getFloat(8);

    float distance = active->distance(destx, desty); // calculated by sqrt(pow(curent character x pos - destx, 2), pow(current character y pos - desty, 2))

    float delta_X = active->vDistance(base_x, destx); // calculated by sqrt(pow(base_x - destx, 2))
    float delta_Y = active->vDistance(base_y, desty);  // calculated by sqrt(pow(base_y - desty, 2))

    float cosa = delta_X / distance;
    float sina = delta_Y / distance;



    int mapx = 1;
    int mapy = 1;

    if(distance > 8)///active sync
    {
        for(float dist = 8; dist < distance;dist+=8)
        {
            base_x += mapx * (cosa * 8);
            base_y += mapy * (sina * 8);
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "[ACTIVESYNC]NEXT SYNC ACK X : " << base_x << " Y : " << base_y;
         }
    }
```

What I'm doing here wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cosa" (and cosb) are apparently dimensionless.  (i.e. meters / meters)

"mapx" (and "mapy") are also dimensionless.

Note that in your for loop, base_x, base_y describe a point on the map. 
And the 2 interesting computations in that loop

```
base_x += mapx * (cosa * 8);
base_y += mapy * (sina * 8);
```

become **meaningless** by attempting to add dimensionless numbers to a point.  It might be ok to multiply by dimensionless numbers, but it is unreasonable to add dimensionless numbers to map points.

I suggest cosa and cosb be changed to represent the distance (i.e. meters) for each step.

```
float cosa = delta_X / 8;  // size of steps in x direction
float sina = delta_Y / 8;  // size of steps in y direction
```

Now the for loop can add 8 steps of cosa and sina appropriately to describe the path way points, and cosa and sina both have appropriate dimensions for the next computation.

The for loop can simplify to :

```
  for(int step = 0; step < 8; step += 1)
  {
     base_x += (mapx * cosa);
     base_y += (mapy * sina);

     // remove or adapt the following 
     std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::left << (step+1) << std::setw(10) 
               << base_x  <<  std::setw(10) << base_y << std::endl;

     // you were using:
     //BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "[ACTIVESYNC]NEXT SYNC ACK X : " 
     //                         << base_x << " Y : " << base_y;
  }
```

My dummy code outputs:

```
base  x/y  301 679
dest  x/y  360 630
delta x/y   59 -49

step_x  = 7.375
step_y  = -6.125

step      base_x    base_y
0         301       679       
1         308.375   672.875   
2         315.75    666.75    
3         323.125   660.625   
4         330.5     654.5     
5         337.875   648.375   
6         345.25    642.25    
7         352.625   636.125   
8         360       630
```

Do these way points look more what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much, but i wanted to spilt path every 8 U distance.

Comment: My dummy code created 8 equal steps between the start and end point, and the sum of the 8 steps should add up to be 'distance'. So what is U?  Are you thinking U

Comment: U didn't understand, when i have 16 distance, i want it to spilt into 2 steps (16 / 8 = 2) but i figured it own, thankyou for the base code.

Comment: Oh, you mean you want way-points on the path to be 8 U apart?  In that case, Distance is 76.6942 U, so you will probably want 10 steps, 8 in the middle, and each end point.  You will have to decide at which endpoint you want the 'short' step.

Comment: I divided distance by 8 and i do form it steps, everything work fine ;).